# Run jupyter nbconvert with ipython

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

**Context:**

I am trying to run a ruby script that launch the following command:

`jupyter nbconvert --to html --execute filename.ipynb`

I am getting the folowing error :

```
Executing notebook with kernel: python2
[NbConvertApp] ERROR | Error while converting 'filename.ipynb'

...

ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9ae86a16defc> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().magic(u'matplotlib inline')
      2 import matplotlib

...    

ImportError: No module named matplotlib
ImportError: No module named matplotlib
```

**Search:**

After some google research I found that it is because the script is executed using python2 instead of ipython.

**Questions:**

How can I force jupyter nbconvert to use ipython ?

Comment: assuming you work on unix, can you execute the following command : `less \`which jupyter\` ` and tell what's the first line ? it should be something like #!/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.6

Comment: #!/home/champb/anaconda3/bin/python

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me
`jupyter nbconvert --to html --execute filename.ipynb --xecutePreprocessor.kernel_name=python3`.